# Why surah "at-Tawbah" also known as "Baraah"

Tags: quran, surat-at-tawbah

Why Surah "at-Tawbah" is called "Bara'ah "what is the meaning of Bara'ah.

Comment: It is called at-Tawbah or baraa'a(h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called so because of the first word of its first verse:

> **براءة** من الله ورسوله إلى الذين عاهدتم من المشركين
>
> ***Barā'at**un Mina Allāhi Wa Rasūlihi 'Ilá Al-Ladhīna `Āhadttum Mina Al-Mushrikīna*
>
> **[This is a declaration of] disassociation**, from Allah and His Messenger, to those with whom you had made a treaty among the polytheists.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:1](http://quran.com/9/1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

surah taubah first word is "بَرَآءَةٌ"  and sometime we called surah Bara'ah .
براءة من الله ورسوله إلى الذين عاهدتم من المشركين

Barā'atun Mina Allāhi Wa Rasūlihi 'Ilá Al-Ladhīna `Āhadttum Mina Al-Mushrikīna

[This is a declaration of] disassociation, from Allah and His Messenger, to those with whom you had made a treaty among the polytheists

بَرَّاءَة  ( اسم ): أَدَاة بَرْي الْأَقْلام

device for sharpening pencils - the sharpener of the pencil

بَرَاءَة  ( اسم ): تَبَرُّؤ

absolution 
- process in Christianity by which one is forgiven 
- state of releasing someon...
المزيد

بَرَاءَة  ( اسم ): تَبْرِئَة

clearance 
- state of releasing someone 
- denial;disownment;refusal 
- release or acq...
المزيد

بَرَاءَة مِن  ( اسم ): خُلُوّ مِنْ

being free from ; freedom from

بَرَاءَة  ( اسم ): رُخْصَة

authorization ; letters patent ; license ; patent ; permit ; release

بَرَاءَة  ( اسم ): سَذَاجَة

artlessness ; guilelessness ; ingenuousness ; innocence ; naivety

بَرّاءَة  ( اسم ): سِكّينُ جَيْب

penknife ; pocketknife

بَرَاءَة  ( اسم ): شَهَادَة

certificate ; degree ; diploma

بَرَاءَة  ( اسم ):

blamelessness ; guiltlessness ; inculpability ; innocence

بَرَاءَة  ( اسم ):

concession ; franchise ; leave ; permission ; warrant(y)

Comment: When you copy paste from a dictionary like almaany you should mark the quotes and add a link. Most of the translated meanings are irrelevant and don't help answering the question.